# What is the purpose of the crimp on a moka funnel?

Tags: equipment, moka

Spurred by [this](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/2024/262) recent [moka](/questions/tagged/moka) question...

The funnel on my moka pot has a "crimp" -- a little ring-shaped indentation -- around the middle, similar to this one from Bialetti:

[image: moka pot funnel with arrow pointing to crimp]

**What is the purpose of this crimp?**

It is indented toward the middle of the funnel (i.e., not protruding out of the funnel). It's far too low to indicate recommended "fill line" for quantity of grounds (for my taste anyway!) There's no other attachment that fits into it, nor does it engage with any other part on the pot (e.g., the top lip of the funnel sits on the moka pot base). It's one piece of sheet metal; e.g., this isn't a point where two pieces attach. Some moka pots have funnels that have this crimp, and others are solid/flat around the side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The crimp is there to support the [reducer](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/2026/127)! The reducer slots into the funnel, and sits on the ridge. You then put coffee on top of it, allowing you to use less coffee in larger pots.

Comment: Fantastic, and glad you got an answer to your question also :) I didn't receive a "reducer" in my kit, so I wonder why my pot has a crimp... or where I could purchase a suitable reducer!

Comment: @hoc_age I haven't been able to find anywhere that sells them, they seem to be quite rare!